# Is there a way to dereference a void pointer in C?

Tags: c, memory

The `calloc` function in C returns a **void pointer** but the memory bytes pointed to are already initialized with values, How is this is achieved?

I am trying to write a custom calloc function in C but can't find a way to initialize the allocated memory bytes

My code

```
#include "main.h"

/**
 * _calloc - Allocate memory for an array
 * @nmemb: Number of elements
 * @size: Size of each element
 *
 * Description: Initialize the memory bytes to 0.
 *
 * Return: a Void pointer to the allocated memory, if error return NULL
 */
void *_calloc(unsigned int nmemb, unsigned int size)
{
        unsigned int i, nb;
        void *ptr;

        if (nmemb == 0 || size == 0)
                return NULL;

        nb = nmemb * size;

        ptr = malloc(nb);

        if (ptr == NULL)
                return NULL;

        i = 0;
        while (nb--)
        {
/*How do i initialize the memory bytes?*/
                *(ptr + i) = '';
                i++;
        }

        return (ptr);
}
```

Comment: Please show your custom calloc function. What are you calling to get the memory? Anyway, void pointers can be cast to any other pointer type and dereferenced as normal. Otherwise nobody would be able to use `malloc` and `calloc` returned pointers. If you do a search you will find countless examples.

Comment: Use an `unsigned char *` to point to the memory and write each byte.

Comment: A `void` pointer can be cast to another type and the result can be dereferenced.

Comment: The `calloc` does not care what type the caller will use. It sets every byte to `0` by filling the memory block. It might use `memset()` or it might do it directly. The `memset()` does not care either. It fills every byte.

Comment: I have edited the question to add code

Comment: @WeatherVane; Every attempt to dereference the void pointer to initialize the memory bytes leads to compilation errors because the pointer is a void type. Is there a way to set the bytes to 0 despite the pointer being a void type?

Comment: No, you cannot set the bytes directy using a void pointer.  But you *can* cast (convert) the void pointer to another kind of pointer, say a char pointer, and use that.

Comment: Well, the `memset()` function also takes a `void*` pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use pointer to another type to dereference it.

example:

```
void *mycalloc(const size_t size, const unsigned char val)
{
    unsigned char *ptr = malloc(size);
    if(ptr) 
        for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++) ptr[index] = val;
    return ptr;
}
```

or your version:

```
//use the correct type for sizes and indexes (size_t)
//try to have only one return point from the function
//do not use '_' as a first character of the identifier 
void *mycalloc(const size_t nmemb, const size_t size)
{
    size_t i, nb;
    char *ptr = NULL;

    if (nmemb && size)
    {
        nb = nmemb * size;
        ptr = malloc(nb);
        if(ptr)
        {
            i = 0;
            while (nb--)
            {
                    //*(ptr + i) = 'z';
                    ptr[i] = 'z';  // isn't it looking better that the pointer version?
                    i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Then you can use it assigning to other pointer type or casting.

example:

```
void printByteAtIndex(const void *ptr, size_t index)
{
    const unsigned char *ucptr = ptr;

    printf("%hhu\n", ucptr[index]);
}

void printByteAtIndex1(const void *ptr, size_t index)
{
 
    printf("%hhu\n", ((const unsigned char *)ptr)[index]);
}
```

Comment: Any comment silent DV-ter?

Comment: I'm was bit concerned about the return type. The function prototype declares a return type of void * but the type of ptr is char *.

Comment: Thanks a lot, code compiled successfully with expected results.

 But I still don't understand why the void * function didn't throw any compile errors even though the return type is char *.

Comment: @NwaburuEmekaChristian, because C does not require any braindead cast from `void*` as C++ does